# The asset "myasset.png" is not present in the asset pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, asset-pipeline

Error: `Sprockets::Rails::Helper::AssetNotFound in Restaurants#index`
`Showing /Users/juliencorbin/code/JulienCorb/myapp/app/views/components/_explanations.html.erb where line #13 raised:`
`The asset "myasset.png" is not present in the asset pipeline.`

I did not change anything ! I just started my rails development server as usual, and I get the following error for *all* my images that are in `myapp/app/assets/images/` .

for example, I use my images in my views this way: `<%= image_tag("myasset.png")%>`

I tried to run `rails tmp:cache:clear` and then `rails assets:precompile` but it did not work.

I really do not sea where it could come from, I just left this project aside for two days and worked on a react project since then. So perhaps is there a link between both projects but I cannot see to what extend.

any Idea ?

Comment: make sure the myasset.png exist in the image folder

Comment: It does exist in the image folder.

Comment: ok. This may be silly sometimes, but ensure you are using the correct extension of image. like jpg or png.

Comment: It is the right extension; as said in my post it concerns all my files in my images folder. It was working perfectly, I did not add or remove any file from the last time I ran my development server. It is just so weird...

Answer (score 0):

You just have to do rails db:setup.